# Yet Another: List of Android Holo Drawable Icons?

Tags: android, icons, drawable

I'm lost in the Internet trying to find a reasonable list of all icons available under R.drawable, but the [only that's not 404 is for android 2.2](http://androiddrawableexplorer.appspot.com/). Is there anything similar for the new Android UI?

Comment: sorry about asking, but... why closed? There's a bunch of other questions like this and this is the first one with a reasonable answer. This is not directly about code but is very important while coding an application since you have to know what icons you can use in the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*I hope, in attempting to answer you question, I am not wrong in assuming the following. If I am, please do correct.*

I am not aware of any new updates to that list of `drawables` in the site you have linked and personally, I have never found any similar websites with a comprehensive list of `drawables` for the newer platforms.

However, if you are looking specifically for the *new Android UI* (I am assuming, you mean ICS and above), you will find a decent list of `drawables` here: https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere/tree/master/library/res
It is not an exhaustive list though.

This link is to an Android Library called [Holo Everywhere](http://www.holoeverywhere.com/).

That being said, the best place to find `drawables` for the latest platform is right where you have setup your platforms for *eclipse*. On my workstation, I can get access to the default resources (platform specific) here:

> C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-16\data\res

This has every resource used for the platform in question and I find it very useful especially while theming. I can refer to the XML's and see how they are setup.

Comment: Why didn't I tried the SDK folder? duh
Specifically, all the icons can be found under *drawable-hdpi* folder (and some other resolution folders, like mdpi etc). Thank you so much for the tip!

Comment: @Igoru: Glad to have helped. :-)

Comment: +1 Wow this is a great answer! I had never thought that all the Android resources must be somewhere locally on my disc! I've been searching for source online... how embarrassing!

Comment: @TwiceCircled: Happens to all of us fella. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If you are after the ActionBar icons, Google have provided them on their Developer site under the headline "ActionBar":
http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html

Direct link to the zip file:
http://developer.android.com/downloads/design/Android_Design_Icons_20120814.zip

Comment: I've already seen this. This is just a very small list of the icons available.